# Xamarin Android google libraries defining the same class

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services, google-ads-api

I updated the libraries on my Xamarin Android application, and I get the following error:
com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zza is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\120\lp\107\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/ads/zza.class, obj\Debug\120\lp\116\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/ads/zza.class

Here are the libraries that collide based on the manifest files found in these folders:

- com.google.android.gms.gass -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gass version 120.0.0.7
- com.google.android.gms.ads.impl -> I assume it's Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads version 121.3.0

Is there any thoughts how can I overcome this issue? My app does not build. I tried many version combinations, none of them helped.

I tried many version combinations, none of them helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the android natived library: **com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass 20.0.0**, its last updated time is Apr 07, 2021. This is the  **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gass nuget package 120.0.0.x** in the xamarin.

And the native library **com.google.android.gms: play-services-ads version 20.0.0** is published at Apr 05, 2021. So I created a sample to test the two nuget packages:

1. Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads version 120.0.0
2. Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gass version 120.0.0.7

The error message disappeared. In addition, you can also uninstall the **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gass** and only use the **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads version 121.3.0**, it should contains the api in the **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gass**.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, I removed Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gass, and went for the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads version 121.3.0, but this introduced another collision.
The final solution involved downgrading to Xamarin.Firebase.Measurement.Connector 119.0.0.7, Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads and related packages to 120.6.0.1, and Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement and related packages to 120.1.2.1.